# What purpose of path structure

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel

I want to understand purpose of `path` structure.

```
struct path {
    struct vfsmount *mnt;
    struct dentry *dentry;
}
```

It was added in 2.6.25 and used by fs_struct, file, nameidata and other file system structures. Before 2.6.25 it was part of these structures.

For example, fs_struct before 2.6.25:

```
struct fs_struct {
    atomic_t count;
    rwlock_t lock;
    int umask;
    struct dentry * root, * pwd, * altroot;
    struct vfsmount * rootmnt, * pwdmnt, * altrootmnt;
};
```

fs_struct in 2.6.25:

```
struct fs_struct {
    atomic_t count;
    rwlock_t lock;
    int umask;
    struct path root, pwd, altroot;
};
```

I want to understand why did they change it in such way? What have they achived?

Comment: Directory entry can hold a mounted file system. Besides that, interesting to investigate overlayfs.

Comment: There is no vfsmount in dentry - https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc1/source/include/linux/dcache.h#L89

Comment: "Can you describe when does it happen?" - For example, a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) shares dentries with the original mount.

Comment: Can you post a little more of context? for example a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Ok, ive changed it.

Comment: the struct got moved out of `fs/namei.c` in [2.6.20](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=346f20ff6020ffa11d40b789069079c56a444ae6), maybe go from there to figure out what you're interested in?